# Magento 2 - mixin for mixin

Tags: magento2

How to build `mixin` for already existing `mixin`? Is it possible at all?

I need to override a function in `Vendor_Module:js/checkout-mixin` that is already a `mixin` for `Magento_Checkout:js/something`

I tried to set it up in `requirejs-config.js` as I would normaly do for defining a mixin, but it is not working.

Set new `mixin` directly for `Magento_Checkout:js/something` is not an option.

Thanks

Comment: I tried the same, but I failed too. I think it is impossible to mixin into a mixin.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry But this is possible if you want to mixin second time an already mixin file.

here best example of breadcrumbs js provided by magento itself

just put this code in your requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Catalog/js/product/breadcrumbs': {
                'Vendor_ModuleName/js/breadcrumbs-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

and put this code in your own vendor_company module in js directory

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Catalog/js/product/breadcrumbs',
    'jquery/ui'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';
    return function (widget) {
        $.widget('mage.breadcrumbs', widget, {
            /**
             * {@inheritdoc}
             */
            _getCategoryCrumb: function (menuItem) {
                //do some custom stuff
                return this._super(menuItem);
            },
        });
        return $.mage.breadcrumbs;
    };
});
```

you can put your other method like

```
_getCategoryCrumb: function (menuItem) {
                //do some custom stuff
                return this._super(menuItem);
            },
```